# Dots in URL query prevent nuxtjs client from loading

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, cloudflare

I have a nuxtjs frontend that users are redirected to from a TikTok advertisement, and TikTok appends a query parameter called TCLID (more info at https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article/tiktok-click-id?lang=en). URLs aren't allowed to have dots in their path, and so nuxtjs client returns an error page that says "Cannot GET /products/7571086278841". It doesn't append the URL query in the error message. I've tried adding nuxtjs middleware but that isn't loaded before the error is thrown, even on server side rendering.

I've tried looking through TikTok settings, CloudFlare settings, and I'm not sure how to handle that in NGINX, so I'm stumped.

Any ideas?